# No Parse Framework in Pods folder after a pod install with cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, cocoapods

I'm trying to import Parse SDK with cocoapods (version `0.37.2`). I have recentl but right after doing a `pod install` There is no Parse.framework in the Pod folder...

When I try to build the app, it failed because with it doesn't find the parse.h from `#import <Parse/Parse.h>` in the bridging header file (which is quite normal because there is no Parse Framework).

Is this possible that as I previously used Parse for another project, when my computer downloads it, it changes the name, such as Parse.framework(2) and then the system can't retrieve it...

Here are the messages from terminal right after the `pod install` (which look good):

`Analyzing dependencies`

`Downloading dependencies`

`Installing Bolts 1.2.0 (was 1.2.0)`

`Installing Parse 1.7.5 (was 1.7.5)`

`Generating Pods project`

`Integrating client project`

And this is what the podfile looks like :

`platform :ios, '8.0'`

`source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'`

`pod 'Parse', '~> 1.7.5'``

Last point: I have recently upgraded my version of rbenv (from `2.1.2` to `2.2.2`) and as Cocoapods is in ruby, I am wondering there could be a link....

Any help would be grateful !

Thanks

Comment: Seeing the same thing :(

Answer (score 1):

What is your version of your cocoapods?

If you are using 0.38.0, it might be changes of CocoaPods make the spec fail. Try to replace

```
pod 'Parse', '~> 1.7.5'
```

with

```
pod 'Parse', podspec: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/siuying/6a548f1924ed3243aeb5/raw/ccea130108b14afbaf22dbe828f75a62d750a4a0/Parse.podspec.json'
```

and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, my version is `0.37.2` so I don't think this is related. Lately, I have recently upgraded my version of rbenv (from `2.1.2` to `2.2.2`) and as Cocoapods rely on ruby, do you think it could be linked ?

Answer (score 0):

If your "Objective-C Bridging Header" in project level it's possible to get this error. You should set this in target level! After added in your target please don't forget to remove from project level. This must solve your problem, I solve like this.

Comment: Thank you very much  for your answer but I am not sure to get it : how could this be related to the bridging header target (which targets at a project level) because there is no files at all inside the Pods/Parse folder... normally I after doing the pod install I should see a Parse.framewok and other files (such as Parse.h), shouldn't I ?